# Deploying Maven assembly ZIP to nexus

Tags: maven, wget, nexus, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

I am using the assembly plugin to build a jar with dependancies and then zip the project. The zip should then be uploaded to nexus. The clean install works and generates the zip file as expected. The deploy command fails:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Analytics Feed Auditor
[INFO]    task-segment: [deploy]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources]
[INFO] Using default encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [compiler:compile]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [resources:testResources]
[INFO] Using default encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile]
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [surefire:test]
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] [jar:jar]
[INFO] [assembly:single {execution: jar-with-dependencies}]
[INFO] Processing DependencySet (output=)
[INFO] Building jar: C:\code\imt workspaces\uat-trunk\AnalyticsAudit\target\AnalyticsAudit-1
.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
[INFO] [assembly:single {execution: RELEASE}]
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: dist.xml
[INFO] Building zip: C:\code\imt workspaces\uat-trunk\AnalyticsAudit\target\AnalyticsAudit-1
.0-RELEASE.zip
[INFO] [install:install]
[INFO] Installing C:\code\imt workspaces\uat-trunk\AnalyticsAudit\target\AnalyticsAudit-1.0.
jar to C:\SVNRepository\com\dec\gbm\gb\gcf\amg\fo\AnalyticsAudit\1.0\AnalyticsAudit-1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\code\imt workspaces\uat-trunk\AnalyticsAudit\target\AnalyticsAudit-1.0-
jar-with-dependencies.jar to C:\SVNRepository\com\dec\gbm\gb\gcf\amg\fo\AnalyticsAudit\1.0\Analytic
sAudit-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\code\imt workspaces\uat-trunk\AnalyticsAudit\target\AnalyticsAudit-1.0-
RELEASE.zip to C:\SVNRepository\com\dec\gbm\gb\gcf\amg\fo\AnalyticsAudit\1.0\AnalyticsAudit-1.0-REL
EASE.zip
[INFO] [deploy:deploy]
altDeploymentRepository = null
Uploading: https://dsnexus.uk.hibm.dec:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/dec/gbm/gb/gcf
/amg/fo/AnalyticsAudit/1.0/AnalyticsAudit-1.0.jar
6K uploaded
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error deploying artifact: Failed to transfer file: https://dsnexus.uk.hibm.dec:8081/nexus/co
ntent/repositories/releases/com/dec/gbm/gb/gcf/amg/fo/AnalyticsAudit/1.0/AnalyticsAudit-1.0.jar. Re
turn code is: 400

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 09 15:58:22 BST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/35M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a few issues here. Firstly, I want to have a custom ZIP filename rather than the default one. Secondly, only the ZIP file should be deployed to Nexus and not the jars. Thirdly, why isn't the deploy working in it's current state? And lastly, can you please tell me how I can automatically download the last release from nexus using wget maybe?

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ....>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.dec.gbm.gb.gcf.amg.fo</groupId>
<artifactId>AnalyticsAudit</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>Analytics Feed Auditor</name>
<description>Analytics Feed Auditor</description>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <name>Internal Releases</name>
        <url>...</url>
    </repository>

    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
        <url>...</url>
    </snapshotRepository>

</distributionManagement>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <name>Nexus Repository</name>
        <url>...</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <name>Nexus Repository</name>
        <url>...</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>Cp1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vicar</groupId>
        <artifactId>vicar</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>
            ${project.basedir}/lib/vicar-3.6.jar
        </systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>...
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>
                                jar-with-dependencies
                            </descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <classpathPrefix>
                                    lib/
                                </classpathPrefix>
                                <mainClass>
                                    com.dec.gbm.gb.gcf.amg.fo.AnalyticsAuditor
                                </mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>RELEASE</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>dist.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

dist.xml

```
<assembly>
<id>RELEASE</id>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<files>
    <file>
        <source>
            target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-jar-with-dependencies.jar
        </source>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    </file>
    <file>
        <source>${project.basedir}/bin/AnalyticsAudit.cmd</source>
        <outputDirectory />
    </file>
    <file>
        <source>
            ${project.basedir}/resources/analytics_audit.properties
        </source>
        <outputDirectory>resources</outputDirectory>
    </file>
    <file>
        <source>${project.basedir}/lib/vicar-3.6.jar</source>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    </file>
</files>
```

I've spent too long on this and tried too much. I'd be very grateful for any help.

Comment: No answers? No one's tried doing this before?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you cannot deploy a zip using a maven-assembly plugin. Assembly part is a part of packaging, while deployment happens later. Check if this link is useful

[Deploying assembly package with maven-release-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244344/deploying-assembly-package-with-maven-release-plugin)

OR

You can use this plugin to deploy the zip or tar file **maven-build-helper-plugin**

Answer (score 0):

When Nexus returns 400 status it means you are uploading artifact which is not allowed to be uploaded into particular repository, for example you are trying to upload snapshot into releases repository.

I guess you are trying to deploy it as a snapshot with "mvn deploy". Try "mvn release:prepare release:perform" insted to release it as stable version into "releases" repository. You should'nt get that 400 status response anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <!--Make it a fat jar-->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!--this is used for inheritance merges-->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!--bind to the packaging phase-->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy a *.zip file to Nexus, you need to have proper `pom.xml` and `assembly.xml` files.

**This is the pom.xml you need:**

```
<project>
    <groupId>a.b</groupId>
    <artifactId>deploy-to-nexus</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!-- 
         it needs to be 'pom', otherwise maven will
         generate an <artifactId>-<version>.jar file as well
    -->
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <!-- nexus repositories -->
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>deploy-to-nexus-releases</id>
            <url>http://...</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>deploy-to-nexus-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://...</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
             <!-- assembly plugin will be activated by 'mvn package' -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**My comments:**

- There are changes in configuration from `v3.1.1` version of the `maven-assembly-plugin`.
- If you do not change the type of `packaging` in the `pom.xml` then Maven will create you a `*.zip` plus a `*.jar` file as well because of the default value of this property is `jar`.
- If the version of your `pom` ends with `-SNAPSHOT` then your zip file will be uploaded into the repository ends with `snapshots`, otherwise `releases` repository is used.

**An example for assembly.xml:**

```
<assembly>
    <id>bundle</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <!-- add some files -->
        <fileSet>
            <directory>...</directory>
            <outputDirectory>...</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

**Then**

- `mvn clean package` command will create your *.zip file.
- `mvn clean deploy` command will upload your zip to Nexus.

Usually, you are not allowed upload the same version of your artifacts into the `releases` repository twice. If you try to do this then you will get back `status code 400`:

```
Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact a.b:deploy-to-nexus:pom:1.0 from/to ..... (http://.....-releases): Failed to transfer file http://..../deploy-to-nexus/1.0/deploy-to-nexus-1.0.pom with status code 400
```

Hope that it helps you.